# While loop with read and triple <

Tags: linux, bash, shell, while-loop, scripting

In this question:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402750/modify-global-variable-in-while-loop

I found a reference to something like:

```
while read -r dir
do
   echo $dir
done <<<$(find /usr/lib -type d)
```

But I haven't found that in the Bash Advanced Guide.
Is this form correct or it is wrong?

Comment: You are looking for [Here-Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings).

Comment: Although the linked answer is accepted, I don't think it is a good answer at all.
Please read again the useful comments on your [previously posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77299854/bash-while-loop-with-data-from-a-command).

Comment: Thanks @pmf. So it looks it is documented!